# Check usb printer status like jammed paper, ink level etc from command line for a VBScript program

Tags: printing, vbscript, command-line-interface

I've a pc running Windows 7 Pro X64 connected to a plotter HP Designjet 800. Usually I send a lot of DWG files to the plotter and leave it alone working: plotter can take hours for finishing the job. It can happen that some issue occurs that causes a stop: jammed paper, ink finished or other kind of problem and it is very annoying discover at the end of the day that the plotter has stopped printing after few prints or worse not even one print. So in this kind of scenario I thought to realize a procedure for checking plotter status periodically and alert me if something goes wrong by email or by other way. I'd like to implement this solution in VBScript. I tried using WMI via VBScript but I'm not able to get the infos I need. Do you know if there is a way (natively or also using a third-party utility) for checking printer status via command line and getting infos like missing paper, jammed paper, ink level and so on? On HP site there is a little utility but it doesn't work via cli and it can't say if a jammed paper occurs. Thanks a lot guys for your time!

Comment: I've done something similar myself but due to the complexity of the system, storing data back to a database to maintain a log and print queue type scenario, I found it best to build a Windows Service to do it. You will likely come up short if you try to use VBScript.

Comment: Hi Lankymart, thanks for your message. How did you query your printer? Can you also get infos about paper status (e.g. jammed paper occurs)? I can change programming language and use something more flexible and powerful if it can be useful for my goal. Bye

Comment: In our case, it's Card Printers and we use the manufacturers SDK to communicate over USB and pull back information about alarms, statuses, ribbon usage etc. It polls every 10 - 15 seconds for the status as well as pass Jobs to the printer, pass data back and forth from the database etc. The whole process is very bispoke and took us a few months to build and test.